# How I can horizontally expand the announcement list App Body area

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, master-page, css, app

I have an announcement list App, but when I click on an announcement item, the detail view will show the announcement item inside a small part of the page. And the text will be vertically organized , while the horizontal area will be not consumed .

So my question is how I can expand the announcement list fields including  (title, body, date, etc) to expand horizontally . I have shown the item and the associated css using F12 developer tool inside IE:-

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, worked for me:

```
#onetIDListForm
{
    width: 100%;
}
.ms-formbody span input.ms-long
{
    width: 98.3%;
}
td.ms-input.ms-noWrap
{
    width: 100%;
}
```